# CSS or JavaScript for animation

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I want to change my code so that the when my layout changes there is a sliding animation.

It is a 3 column layout and I want the left-most column to shrink a but when the user is focused on the right 2/3 of the screen.

I wrote a simple codepen demoing my code.

I am using JS to transition between two CSS classes, but I wanted to add an sliding transition to it.

I'm not sure if this should be 100% CSS or if I need to use some jQuery animation to get the desired effect.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/glennferrie/pen/vYaLpXo

```js
const leftPane = document.getElementById('leftpane');
const centerPane = document.getElementById('centerpane');
const rightPane = document.getElementById('rightpane');
var addMode2 = function() {
  leftPane.classList.add("mode-2");
  rightPane.classList.add("mode-2");
  centerPane.classList.add("mode-2");
}
var removeMode2 = function() {
  leftPane.classList.remove("mode-2");
  rightPane.classList.remove("mode-2");
  centerPane.classList.remove("mode-2");
}
leftPane.addEventListener("mouseover", function(ev) {
  removeMode2();
});
centerPane.addEventListener("mouseover", function(ev) {
  addMode2();
});
rightPane.addEventListener("mouseover", function(ev) {
  addMode2();
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.left-pane,
.center-pane,
.right-pane {
  padding-block-start: 10vh;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: dotted 2px #333;
  height: 95vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.left-pane {
  width: 25vw;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.center-pane {
  width: 40vw;
}

.right-pane {
  width: 33vw;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.left-pane.mode-2 {
  width: 10vw;
}

.center-pane.mode-2 {
  width: 47vw;
}

.right-pane.mode-2 {
  width: 40vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-pane" id="leftpane">
    Left Pane Content
  </div>
  <div class="center-pane" id="centerpane">
    Center Pane Content
  </div>
  <div class="right-pane" id="rightpane">
    Right Pane Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `grid` and animate the width of the columns. The solution below uses the `has()` pseudo-code which is [not yet supported by Firefox](https://caniuse.com/?search=has).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: grid;
  /* Default setting equal width for all columns */
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr 2fr;
  transition: grid-template-columns 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.left-pane,
.center-pane,
.right-pane {
  outline: dotted 2px #333;
  height: 95vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.left-pane {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right-pane {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

/* When center pane OR right pane is hovered, adjust the width of the columns of the parent */
.container:has(.center-pane:hover), .container:has(.right-pane:hover) {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2.5fr 2.5fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-pane">
    Left Pane Content
  </div>
  <div class="center-pane">
    Center Pane Content
  </div>
  <div class="right-pane">
    Right Pane Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot.  can that `has` operation take arguments like: `.center-pane:hover OR .right-pane:hover` -- I guess I could have separate rule for each and widen the column in focus.  I am second-guessing this "columns-in-motion" thing... just trying to provide more room for the content in focus, but all of the motion is giving me vertigo

Comment: @GlennFerrie  I adjusted the code to facilitate the OR question.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by adding `transition` property for your `.left-pane, .center-pane, .right-pane` elements inside CSS. It is best to have it for all three panes as they all change their width on hover.

Here's an example:

```
.left-pane, .center-pane, .right-pane {
  padding-block-start: 10vh;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: dotted 2px #333;
  height: 95vh;
  text-align: center;
  /*  Transition for the width  */
  transition: 250ms width ease;
}
```

As you can see I added 3 properties for the `transition`.

First is time which defines how long will your animation take to complete. Second is property you want to animate, in your case it's `width` and the last one is the interpolator, by default it is set to linear which might be something you want but you can change it, I set it to `ease` to make effect more pleasing to the eyes.

You can read more about `transition` to learn about all the possibilities in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

Comment: this is a great response. I ended up implementing the solution with the ‘grid-template-columns‘ approach